# Establish the limits of integration (as regions types 1 and 2) circular sector $C=(0,0)$ and extremities $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$

Tags: integration, area

I am asked to establish the limits of integration (as regions types 1 and 2) of a region S, which is a circular sector with the center on the origin and whose extremities are on points $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$.

The answers that I got are

Region type 1
$$
\int_{-1}^{0} \int_{-x}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} \cdots dydx + \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} \cdots dydx
$$

Region type 2

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-y}^{y} \cdots dxdy + \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\sqrt{2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}} \cdots dxdy
$$

But the textbook answer is

$$
2y \leq x \leq 2\\
0 \leq y \leq 1
$$

which for me does not make sense.

Am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First, the question in the textbook was to give the limits of integration, not to write the integrals themselves. Also, it is not clear to me **which** problem the "textbook answer" is for.  For the second, integrating with respect to "x" first (your "region type II") you are correct that we need to divide the region of integration into to regions because the formulas for the x- limits change.  First, for y from 0 to 1, x goes from the line x= -y to the line x= y.  Then, for y= 1 to 2, x goes from one side of the circle to the other- from $x= -\sqrt{2- y^2}$ to $x= \sqrt{2- x^2}$.

The region bounded by "$0\le x\le 2y$, $0\le y\le 1$" is the region bounded by the **triangle** with vertices at (0, 0), (1, 2), and (0, 2), not a circular sector.

Comment: yes the question was to find the limits, but they are clearly established on the integral. For both regions it is required to split the area into two integrals, correct? Since also on the type 1 the line below the sector is y=-x (for -1 \leq x \leq 0) and y=x (for 0 \leq x \leq 1)